# QPushButton does not work when added to Layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a QWidget (which is setup as a UI named Ui_Form) that I want it to be part of a QFrame which is already part my QMainWindow; this QWidget is a UI form with buttons and other objects. I tried to add it as part of the layout of the frame, however the problem is that the QPushButtons that are in the Ui_Form stop working when I add the QWidget to the layout, My code is below.

```
## My QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        # pyuic5 code here ...
        self.MyFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.MyFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 560, 1201, 201))
        self.MyFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.MyFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        #  more pyuic5 code here ...

        my_form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        my_form_ui = Ui_Form()
        my_form_ui.setupUi(my_form)
        frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        frame_layout.addWidget(my_form)
        self.MyFrame.setLayout(frame_layout)
```

My Ui_Form class, which used to work before adding it to the layout

```
## My Ui_Form class
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, form):
        # some pyuic5 code here ...
        self.myPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(form)
        self.myPushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(415, 200, 101, 40))
        self.myPushButton.setObjectName("myPushButton")
        self.myPushButton.clicked.connect(self.printHello) 

    def printHello(self):
        print("Hello World!")
```

The MainWindow will display nicely all elements from Ui_Form, but buttons do **NOT** work, eventhough I call setupUi method which will connect the button to the printHello method. Any ideas?

Comment: Camaron you do know that you could avoid these kind of headaches if you stopped using the Designer and just coded PyQt from scratch -- it is just as easy and perhaps easier in the long run -- most folks that I have taught how to do it without the Designer have never even considered looking back because it is simply that easy to do without the Designer and then the code is like 10 times easier to work with and you fully understand what it is doing and not doing rather than some mystical block-box of code that you are not supposed to touch

Comment: Thanks for your response, however rewriting that part might take me more time

Comment: Okay but in the long run just know it will take you a lot less time to write it without the Designer than it will dealing with the various issues you will have to contend with using the Designer -- further later maintenance will also take a lot longer -- it is basically when do you start saving time versus losing it.  And please do not get me wrong -- completely up to you just trying to give you food for thought from someone who has been there and done that kind of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

The problem is `my_form_ui` is a local variable that will be eliminated when you finish executing the `setupUi()` method so the `printHello()` method will no longer exist. With the `QPushButton` that problem is not generated because the ownership is the GUI.

### Solution:

Set `my_form_ui` as an attribute of the class:

```
# ...
my_form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.my_form_ui = Ui_Form()
self.my_form_ui.setupUi(my_form)
frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
# ...
```